# How to replace absolute image src urls with relative path?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have several html files with img tags and absolute image paths. I want to remove the absolute part and just leave a relative path.

Eg.
http://domain1.com/media/uploads/2017/11/image-test-1.jpg
https://domain2.org/photos/uploads/2016/08/anotherimage.png

Those two would end up like this:

images/image-test-1.jpg
images/anotherimage.png

How can I accomplish this?

This is what I currently have:
`preg_replace( "@(http[s]*?://[-\w\.]+)(\/\w+\.(png|jpg))@", 'images/$2', $url );`
It was returning everything up to the uploads dir, but, after some tweaks it doesn't work at all...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My pattern will match from `http` to the last `/` in the url and replace it with `images/`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/1MGIZ))

```
$urls=[
'http://domain1.com/media/uploads/2017/11/image-test-1.jpg',
'https://domain2.org/photos/uploads/2016/08/anotherimage.png'
];

$urls=preg_replace('~https?://(?:[^/]*/)*~','images/',$urls);

var_export($urls);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'images/image-test-1.jpg',
  1 => 'images/anotherimage.png',
)
```

Pattern Explanation:

```
~            #Pattern delimiter
https?://    #Match http:// or https://
(?:          #Start non-capturing group
    [^/]*    #Match zero or more non-slash characters
    /        #Match slash
)            #End non-capturing group
*            #Match zero or more occurrences of the non-capturing group
~            #Pattern delimiter
```

Here is a [pattern demo](https://regex101.com/r/H9zubk/1).  *note, I had to add `\s` to the negated character class to make it match multiple urls in one string.

---

As for your pattern:

```
@
(              #this generates capture group number 1
    http
    [s]*?      #simpler would be: s?
    ://
    [-\w\.]+   #dot doesn't need escaping; this will match [-A-Za-z0-9_.]
)
(              #this generates capture group number 2
    \/         #escaping is not necessary, just use: /
    \w+        #this will match one or more of [A-Za-z0-9_]
    \.         #this will match literal dot
    (png|jpg)  #this generates capture group number 3 containing png or jpg
)
@
```

To repair your pattern:  ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Dvv8B))

- Add `/` to change `[-\w.]` to this: `[-\w./]`
- Change file matching component from `\w+` to `[\w-]+`
- Change the replacement to: `images$2`

Comment: If you need validation that is more strict, please extend your sample strings and explain what fringe cases need to be caught / dealt with.

Comment: Wonderful! I think that's it, all urls would need to replace everything from "http" to the last "/" with "images/".. could you explain this part? `?://(?:[^/]*/`

Comment: @andrux I've added a pattern explanation

Comment: @andrux I've included a review of your pattern.  You were close, but regex isn't always forgiving with "close".